# Using ndk project/library with drivers

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-library

I have this demo project: http://www73.zippyshare.com/v/74674979/file.html which I got for using http://www.aclas.tw/Products/AO1X/ .

My problem for using this is in the documentation. Which does not exist.

I understand how the Java part of the code works but I don't know how to implement this in my project.

I downloaded and installed ndk hoping I would be able to run the project but it crashed at the most important part:

> System.loadLibrary("AclasArmPos");

I don't know what to do and there is no description on how to use it. Except the code itself which I cannot run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the .so files under jni/libs. If you have .so files for multiple architectures, create folders like x86, armv7a within the jni folder and place the .so files in the corresponding folder. If you are using Android studio, the steps to follow are slightly different. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I am using eclipse. The whole code wich I am trying to use is located here: http://www73.zippyshare.com/v/74674979/file.html the password for rar is >> aclas321 <<. I am trying to use this in my own project (using the printing and lcd functions). Thank your very much for helping me.

Comment: I figured it out. I just copied the whole package of driver classes and libAclaArmPos.co in libs undery every architectures.